# Language editor/generator on normal eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I've created my DSL language and code generator using Xtext nad Xtend. But when I want to use it, I need to open my Xtext project and click "Run as-> Launch Runtime Eclipse". Is it possible to have my editor/generator in the normal eclipse run? In other words, I want to download plain eclipse installation,than install some plugin or somehow configure my eclipse, and than create files of my language, have syntax coloring and all editor features, code generation etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to export your plugins and install them into eclipse.

option 1: use `File>Export...>Deployable plugins and fragments` to export your plugins, then install them into an eclipse.  That wizard has an option to deploy them directly into your running eclipse.

option 2: build your plugins using [PDE build](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_feature_build.htm) or [maven/tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php) and create a p2 update site.  Then you can install them into any eclipse you have.

Both options are easier to manage if you create a feature that contains your plugins.  It's easier to export, and easier to install the feature.